# How can I catch the timing of UI actually updated after I call setTranslationY?

Tags: android, user-interface, refresh, translation, screenshot

I know the view won't be updated immediately right after I just called view.setTranslationY(-10.0f) until the main thread return to the idle loop.

I would like to take a screenshot right after the moment when view has been updated but I don't find the callback such as "onTranslationFinished()" or "setOnTranslationEnd()" to give me a chance to do that.

At first, I did like the following code and it actually worked:

```
view.setTranslationY(-10.0f);
view.post(new Runnerable() {
@Override
void run() {
  takeScreenshot();
});
```

But when my cellphone is reaching the memory limitation and it's running slowly,
the method doesn't work as my expectation. takeScreenshot() run before the view actually translated -10.0f.
I know such as postDelayed(100ms) may fix the problem temporarily but it's not a best solution.

Does any way to meet my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add a `onDrawListener` of the view tree observer. Like following code:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDraw() {
                //action
            }
        });`
```

This callback will be invoked when the view tree is about to be drawn.

Comment: I tried to set a breakpoint on onDraw and print a log on that. Unfortunately onDraw is not even called at all. Translation may not cause redraw.

Comment: Actually it will be called. Check your app.gradle file, the `minSdkVersion` needs to be at least `16` , otherwise , it won't be called back. @Keith

Comment: Thanks for your information but I still cannot receive that inform even though I've install a listener. 
I verified on Android system build instead of Gradle build, therefore there won't be SDK version issue.